# Calling CFRunLoop family on a Cocoa application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sockets, core-foundation

I have a cocoa application in which I would like to use *UNIX domain sockets* to communicate with a system-wide daemon.

*In a first step, my client will connect to the daemon and then listen for incoming log statements from the daemon.*

The example I found, *CFLocalServer from Apple*, uses `CFSockets` to communicate between two command line utilities. I was able to set the daemon part of the code nicely, because I am free to decide what function to call in my daemon (`[[NSRunLoop currentLoop] run]` or `CFRunLoopRun()`). However, I have doubts about the client, which is a cocoa application.

In the code sample, the client first create them, connects, adds them as source to the current `CFRunLoop` for listening operations and then calls `CFRunLoopRun();` until cancelled by `CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent());`

**My question is:** can I do all that inside a block on a serial dispatch queue created by an Objective-C cocoa application without interfering with the NSRunLoop in my application's main thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that, although you may want to simply attach the socket to the main run loop and let it run normally (i.e. don't call `CFRunLoopRun()` since its already running).

I would also look at [GCDAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket) which is a very nice wrapper for all of this kind of work if your needs are complicated. It doesn't currently have support for unix domain sockets, but you can use [jdiehl's socketUN branch](https://github.com/jdiehl/CocoaAsyncSocket/commits/socketUN) which adds it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can I attach the socket to the main run loop in a cocoa application? Let's say I execute the code in the application delegate when the application did finish launching (so I am on the main thread).

Comment: Just as you are now, just use `CFRunLoopGetMain()`.  I assume you're already calling `CFSocketCreateRunLoopSource()` and `CFRunLoopAddSource()`. Just add it to the main loop rather than some other loop.